# Factorize polynomial in $\mathbb Z_2[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

What is the most efficient way (less time consuming, algorithmically) to factorize polynomials in $\mathbb Z_2[X]$ ?

For small degree polynomials, I just try every possibilities (like $X^2+1=(X+1)^2$), but it doesn't work well for high degree polynomials. So how can I factorize polynomials of high degree efficiently? (for example polynomial of degree 100).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields

Comment: Specifically http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Factoring_algorithms

Comment: @SamDeHority That's good, that's exactly what I need, thanks !