# Polynomial factorisation on integers modulo n

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, factoring

Is there a known (efficient) algorithm to compute the list of factors of a polynomial modulo $n$ (for any integer $n$)?

For example in $\mathbb Z_8$, $X^2+2X$ has a list of 4 factors (multiplicity 1 for all of them) : $X$, $X+2$, $X+4$ and $X+8$, because 
$$X^2+2X=X(X+2)=(X+4)(X+6)$$

Or in $\mathbb Z_9$, $X^3$ has a list of factors (with multiplicity) $X^3, (X+3)^3, (X+6)^3$ because
$$X^3=(X+3)^3=(X+6)^3=X(X+3)(X+6)$$

PS : I already asked in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664858/factorize-polynomial-in-mathbb-z-2x) for prime $n$ and got nice answers, so the question is more for $n=p^k$ with $p$ prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Factoring Polynomials Modulo Composites](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/1997/CMU-CS-97-136.ps).

Comment: Alt link:  https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a327984.pdf